# How can I assign an id value before press a button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem, I put it very straightforward:

I have a table with a name, a quantity and a button that's supposed to change the quantity's value.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>name1</td>
    <td><button id = "add1" data-add = "1">add</button></td>
    <td id = "quant1">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name2</td>
    <td><button id = "add2" data-add = "2">add</button></td>
    <td id = "quant2">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
var quant = 0;
var id;
$('#add' + id).on('click', function() {
  id = $(this).attr('data-add');
  quant++;
  $('#quant' + id).html(quant);
});
```

I thought something like

```
    var quant = 0;
    var id;
    $('#add' + $(this).attr('data-add')).on('click', function() {
      id = $(this).attr('data-add');
      quant++;
      $('#quant' + id).html(quant);
    });
```

But doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `this` at the point you use it references the highest level element - the window - not the `#add` elements themselves. A better method would be to use common classes to DRY up your code and use DOM traversal to negate the need to identify individual elements. Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name1</td>
        <td><button class="add" data-add="1">add</button></td>
        <td class="quantity">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name2</td>
        <td><button class="add" data-add="2">add</button></td>
        <td class="quantity">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
    var increment = $(this).data('add');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').text(function(i, text) {
        return parseInt(text, 10) + increment;
    })
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mbqq5t7e/)

Comment: Another question about this: how can I add the returned value in the function to an attribute "value"?

Comment: Just set it in the function, `var value = parseInt(text, 10) + increment; return `value`.